# How to sign Android release build using uploaded release keystore on AppCenter?

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

My question is regarding this document, [Android Code Signing Setup in App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/code-signing).

For some reason, my company prefers to not have `release.keystore` under version control. So, I want to use [Upload everything to App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/code-signing#2-upload-everything-to-app-center). Unfortunately, they didn't provide any sample code I follow like what they did for [Storing Signing Details in the Repository with Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/code-signing#3-storing-signing-details-in-the-repository-with-environment-variables).

So, I am wondering has anyone have the experience of that? I uploaded my `release.keystore` into AppCenter, I added the Store pass, Key Alias, and Key pass. I don't know how to reference it then in my build config file. Should I reference it? If yes, how? If no, then what might be the issue?

Currently, my build file looks like this:

```
android {
    ....

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
            storeFile file('../keystore/debug.keystore')
        }

        release {

        }
    }
....
}
```

And this is the error I got on AppCenter:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

This is how I configured on AppCenter:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

1. Delete release block from `signingConfigs` under the `app/build.gradle` file.
2. Delete `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` from the `buildTypes.release`.

Note: Step 2 is required if you want to keep lines under the release block.